# Date.js 'tt' format doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, date, datejs

I am using the following javascript code:

```
var d = Date.parseExact('Jun 4, 2012 12:30:00 AM','MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt');
alert(d.toString('MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt'));
```

the result of the alert is:

```
Jun 4, 2012 12:30:00 PM
```

seems like Date.js doesn't really care about my 'tt' format....
is it a bug??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will apply to you, but [I found this](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/issues/detail?id=89) today.

As it turns out, the `.js` file available for download on the main site is a bit out of date. Updating to the version mentioned in this issue fixed a similar issue for me.

Comment: Thank you for this. You saved me a ton of time.. http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js for those interested.

Comment: You should use the fork Date.js: Evolved (https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs)
This fork was started improve and maintain DateJS. To keep what is still the most full featured JavaScript Date library alive, maintained, and improved.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it do care if you use the tt format. It seems if you do parse 05:30 AM instead then you get the expected result, but when you go over 12 then it changes into PM.

(You get the opposite result if you start with PM, then you get AM.)

Here I'm a bit on unstable ground as I'm not too familiar with the AM PM system. But isn't those from 00:00 to 11:59?

Anyway seems that's what the Date.js library does, it changes the AM of your 12:30 time to PM.

Comment: format h means 1-12 (as seen in documentation), so,  12:30 is like 00:30 AM... according to my understanding